# deploying VB.net website with MySQL server database into portable device (pendrive)

Tags: asp.net, mysql, deployment, mono, portable-applications

I have developed a web application using VB.net with MySQL database,
now I need to deploy this application to a portable device such as pendrive/harddisk so user can use this application through the portable device in different computers.

Is there any possible way to do this?

I found this [asp.net on apache](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx) but I am not sure will this work for me or not.

EDIT

Is Mod_MONO able to do what I wanted?

Comment: Seems odd to have written this as a web program (Asp.net) when an executable would of suited far better. Was there a reason?

Comment: ya, my client insist on web application over desktop application...

Answer (score 0):

websites /web application can be deployed on web server only.
for asp.net it is IIS .

to make it portable you need Microsoft Virtual PC. create a virtual machine and install your app on that , then keep that in Portable Device